# Statistical usage of WPF / Winforms / ClickOnce / 

Tags: wpf, winforms, statistics, clickonce

I'm after some sort of statistic of usage of WPF in programming application.

Is there any reference online or stats, such as the browser usage stats, for WPF vs Winforms, ClickOnce vs MSI, C# vs. VB, etc.?

Also is there such thing per year? (ie. tracking the evolution in the usage of WPF)

I've googled but no luck so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly scientific, but you could use the StackOverflow feed data to get stats on how many questions are asked regarding each of these technologies.

Other than that, I think this is a really tough one since many of the apps are inside firewalls. Maybe one of the big research firms has stats, but even their stats would be estimates (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Another non-scientific idea is to type winforms or wpf in the nuget package manager and see how many downloads the first ten nuget packages have.